# How to read a csv file in DictReader mode

Tags: python, csv

I am new to Python and trying to read a csv file as a dictionary. I have written the following code but it does not give me any output...

```
from pathlib import Path
import csv
csvpath = Path("budget_data.csv")
with open(csvpath, 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Any error ? include that in your post.

Comment: There is no error msg the code does not run

Comment: Above code work's fine for me, check if file is empty.